# Is flamegraph able to show all function calls?

Tags: c++, flamegraph

I know there is a profiling tool called flame graph that is able to quickly identify the performance bottleneck of a binary.

Actually I don’t need to know the performance stats. Instead, I am only interested in the stack trace. The flame graph is able to visualize all the history stack trace. Flamegraph can contain much more info than a traditional GDB crash stacktrace because it remembers all history function calls.

So my question is : can flamegraph satisfy what I am looking for? I heard that flamegraph do samplings, so I am afraid it will lose function calls.

I found many flamegraph examples from this webpage: https://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html#C++. The flamegraph is exactly what I am looking for, because I can zoom in and out to check the function calls. The only concern here is: I heard that prof tool such as perf only do sampling to collect stacktraces by a sampling ratio, so the flamegraph might not faithfully demonstrate all function calls.

In short, what I am looking for is: flamegraph minus the performance stats but plus the 100% function call histories.

Comment: The reason I ask this question is : I am looking for a way to understand a legacy codebase quickly. The codebase is several years old and the developers come and go. So I think by leveraging the flamegraph tool , I can run some test case and get some knowledge and confidence about what functions are called, and some other runtime insights.

Comment: If you mostly want to know what functions are called, gprof can show you that pretty easily (not certain, but flame graph probably collects and uses grpof data). Among other things, it can count the number of times each function is called. Although it collects some data by sampling (so things can get lost), function call count is collected deterministically, so it should never "lose" a function call.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a way to achieve my goal. It's a hack by leveraging existing flamegraph function.

Step 1: instrument the code base by a patch similar to following:

```
+#include <iostream>
+#include <vector>
+#include <sstream>
+
+extern thread_local std::vector<std::string> thread_local_stack;
+
+struct tracer_t {
+    tracer_t(std::string method) {
+        thread_local_stack.emplace_back(std::move(method));
+        std::ostringstream oss;
+        for (int i = 0; i < thread_local_stack.size(); ++i) {
+            if (i) {
+                oss << ";";
+            }
+            oss << thread_local_stack[i];
+        }
+        printf("%s 1", oss.str().c_str());
+    }
+
+    ~tracer_t() {
+        thread_local_stack.pop_back();
+    }
+};
+
+inline std::string methodName(const std::string& prettyFunction)
+{
+    size_t colons = prettyFunction.find("::");
+    size_t begin = prettyFunction.substr(0, colons).rfind(" ") + 1;
+    size_t end = prettyFunction.rfind("(") - begin;
+
+    return prettyFunction.substr(begin,end) + "()";
+}
+
+#define __METHOD_NAME__ methodName(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
+
+#define LOG_CALL tracer_t _token(__METHOD_NAME__)
```

declare the thread local stack somewhere:

```
+thread_local std::vector<std::string> thread_local_stack;
```

add `LOG_CALL` macro at the beginning of the functions you want to trace. There might be hundreds of them, I am not aware of any automatic tool, so I added it manually.

The above code works in clang compiler.

step 2: compile the code, and run a test case that you are interested in. We will get the traces. The content should look like this:

```
func1 1
func1;func2 1
func1;func2;func3 1
func1;func2;func4 1
func1;func2;func3 1
func2 1
...
```

The above format is recognizable by flamegraph tool from https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph/blob/master/flamegraph.pl. I learned this format by trying this example: https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph/blob/master/files.pl

step 3: run the flamegraph with "--flamechart" option because we want the X axis sorted by time and disable the "auto-merging" in flamegraph.

The difference between "flamechart" and "flamegraph" is: flamegraph is designed to study perf bottleneck, so many samples are merged (sum). For this post's purpose, we need to sort the X-axis by time and never merge.

Use the following cmd:

```
cat ~/d/output.txt |  ./flamegraph.pl --hash --countname=bytes --flamechart  > /tmp/out.svg
```

Then I got the flamechart that I want in out.svg.